# Using inherited widget on child element in Jquery Ui Widget Factory

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, draggable, jquery-ui-widget-factory

I am trying to make my custom draggable widget with JQuery Ui factory, which inherits draggable.

It works fine when the element itself, but I need to use draggable only on its child element. Is it possible to use with ihreritance or I should use just apply  draggable as usual?

```
    $.widget("ui.myDraggable", $.ui.draggable, {

        options: {
            item: null //Selector for child element
        },

        _build: function() {

            var $item = $(this.options.item);

            //This makes container draggable
            $.ui.draggable.prototype._create.call(this);

            //How can I make only inner draggable, if I still apply widget on container?
            //Something like this:
            //$.ui.draggable.prototype._create.call(this.options.item);           

        }
}
```

Here is my complete example:
http://jsfiddle.net/vlrt/j1uogfrx/4/

Comment: You can't (ok, you can, but shouldn't) do this, think of the recursion! Just make two widgets -- one for the parent and one for the child node. On a side note, don't call the "parent"-widget's initialiser that way, use [`this._super()`](http://api.jqueryui.com/jQuery.widget/#method-_super).

Comment: Thanks a lot. Is it safe enough to apply draggable inside other widget?
http://jsfiddle.net/vlrt/j1uogfrx/6/